# Git: Add updated file from non-cloned local to remote github

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a Github repository called Animals. Then I create the file cat.txt in the directory Animals and upload (drag-and-drop) it to the Github repo Animals. At this point Github doesn't know where cat.txt came from, i.e., the upload did not create a .git in my Animals directory, did it? So I go to another computer and clone Animals onto it. That cloned directory Animals does in fact have a connection to my Github Animals, correct? I can do `git remote` and the Github Animals should return.

Let's say I have a third computer where I have a newer version of cat.txt in no way connected to the Github Animals. How can I merge this newer cat.txt into the repo? So far I've done a `git init` in that local Animals directory and committed cat.txt. So now what should I do to have the newer version override the Github version? Also, what should I do to have the original directory from which I did the drag-and-drop also "connected" the the Github Animals repo?

Comment: It sounds like you should clone the repo onto that third computer, copy the new version of the file into the relevant place, then add, commit and push as you normally would for any other change.

Comment: Sure, but there must be a more "elegant" way, no?

Comment: Why do you consider that inelegant?

Comment: It seems like something someone like me would do since I don't know git that well. It's classic brute force, isn't it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. I think you can do git remote add origin remote_repo_path;git pull --rebase;git push

Comment: I'm writing a series of git related blog posts/tutorials that may help you get more confortable with git; hope it helps: http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-init/ && http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-clone/ && http://pedrorijo.com/blog/git-workflow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I merge this newer cat.txt into the repo?

You actually can add cat.txt to the local cloned repo even if it is not in said clone:

```
cd /path/to/cloned/repo
git --work-tree=/path/to/parent/folder/of/cat add -- cat.xt
git diff
git status
git commit -m "Add cat.txt"
git push
```

> Also, what should I do to have the original directory from which I did the drag-and-drop also "connected" the the Github Animals repo?

You can do:

```
cd /path/to/Animals
git init .
git remote add origin /url/repo/Animal
git fetch
git branch master origin/master
git reset --hard
```

That will reset the content of that folder to the one from GitHub.